# Compare csv files rank order

Tags: python, csv, rank

I am trying to compare the first 300 lines of one csv file to another. I am iterating through each line of the first file. Within that iteration I am iterating through the second file, counting each iteration, until I find a match. Then I am outputing the counting value (row of the matched line in the second file) into a text file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    import csv

with open('/Volumes/cachannel/CUTLER/subsampling/in-silico_IDC18_GFP18_names_only.csv', 'rb') as file1:
    file1reader = csv.reader(file1)
    with open('/Volumes/cachannel/CUTLER/subsampling/ICD18_GFP18_names_only.csv', 'rb') as file2:
        file2reader = csv.reader(file2)

        header1 = file1reader.next()
        header2 = file2reader.next()

        count = 0

        with open("Rank_results.txt", 'a') as outfile:
            while count < 300:
                print(count)
                for line1 in file1reader:
                    linenum = 1
                    for line2 in file2reader:
                        if line1 == line2:
                            print('match found')
                            outfile.write(str(linenum))
                        else:
                            linenum += 1
                count += 1
```

The error I am now getting is that it only finds the first match and doesn't find any others - when I know there are more.

Just to be clear here is an example:

File 1:

```
Bob
Sue 
Sally
Herald
```

File 2:

```
Sue 
Bob 
Herald 
Sally
```

Output file:

```
2 1 4 3
```

Comment: You're always going to print 1 since you never update the linenum variable

Comment: I updated the code to include an update to the linenum variable if a match is not found, but still no luck...

Comment: When I run your code I get an empty `Rank_results.txt` file as the result and it never prints `match found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is trying to iterate over the second file multiple times. In order to iterate over its entire contents more than once, you need to close and reopen it. You can also let Python count the line numbers automatically by using `enumerate()` and count the number of matches by storing them in a list and checking its length.

Another problem is the sample input files don't have the header lines in them. Assuming they do contain them, the following should do what you want:

```
import csv

MAX_COUNT = 300
filename1 = '/Volumes/cachannel/CUTLER/subsampling/in-silico_IDC18_GFP18_names_only.csv'
filename2 = '/Volumes/cachannel/CUTLER/subsampling/ICD18_GFP18_names_only.csv'
matches = []

with open(filename1, 'rb') as file1:
    file1reader = csv.reader(file1)
    header1 = file1reader.next()

    for line1 in file1reader:
        with open(filename2, 'rb') as file2:
            file2reader = csv.reader(file2)
            header2 = file2reader.next()

            for linenum, line2 in enumerate(file2reader, start=1):
                if line1 == line2:
                    print('match found')
                    matches.append(str(linenum))
                    if len(matches) >= MAX_COUNT:
                        break

        if len(matches) >= MAX_COUNT:
            break

with open("Rank_results.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(' '.join(matches) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works flawlessly. I did not know about enumerate(), so that will be very helpful in the future. My only question is when you check to see  if len(matches) >= MAX_COUNT, why do you have it in two different places?

Comment: You're welcome. I put a length check in each of the `for` loops. A second one was needed so if the condition was encountered during the inner one, it would propagate to the outer one, allowing both to terminate early as soon as it happens. This kind of thing can also be handled by using exceptions, which might have more "Pythonic"...